# How to create a Edit Form with a high number of properties of different types

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor-server-side

I use Blazor Server and have a class with about 100 properties that I want to edit in a form. These properties are of different types (`int`, `decimal`, `string`, `DateTime`, `ints` that are based on a selected value in a dropdown, so I need the options for these as well, multi-selects, `bool`,...); some are required properties, some not, the display order is not based on their types, so just using a bunch of arrays with the fields is not possible. How can I generalize my backend and my frontend to edit these properties without the need to explicitly and manually create a field for each property in my form?

There are so many tutorials regarding forms, but all with just a few properties and explicitly manually created labels and input for each property.

**Update regarding current store of selection**

My selection fields currently look like this:

In the DTO:

```cs
public class MyDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SelectedTag { get; set; }
}
```

In the UI:
I get the Dropdown options in a separate dictionary (The `InputComponent` does just some UI stuff like adding floating labels), the `DropDownCategory.Tag` is currently an Enum. Based on that, I get the options from the `_dropDownOptions` Dictionary.
Here is a simplified version:

```
<EditForm Model="_myDto">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary/>

            <InputComponent ValueId="SelectedTag "
                            LabelText="Selected Tag"
                            UnitText=""
                            HelpText="">
                <InputFragment>
                    <InputSelect id="SelectedTag " @bind-Value="_myDto.SelectedTag " class="form-select">
                        @foreach (var value in _dropDownOptions[DropDownCategory.Tag])
                        {
                            <option value="@value.Id">@value.Value</option>
                        }
                    </InputSelect>
                </InputFragment>
            </InputComponent>

</EditForm>


@code {
    private DtoCloneEdit? _myDto;

    private Dictionary<DropDownCategory, List<DropDown>>? _dropDownOptions;

}
```

Comment: You need a propertyGrid. It use reflexion to display Inputs according to their types. It allows you to edit your object. This one is a bit old, maybe you can find another one https://github.com/toreaurstadboss/BlazorPropertyGrid/tree/main/BlazorPropertyGrid

Comment: The problem is you have selections. So anyway you have to add hundreds of selections to your page. Can you post how will you store the selections?

Comment: @QiangFu I added an update for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code for a reference.
MyModel.cs (I only create 3 property for test)

```
    public class MyModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public Decimal Score { get; set; }
        
    }
```

OptionsRepository.cs  (To store the options)

```
    public class OptionsRepository
    {
        public OptionsRepository()
        {
            Name = new()
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "Tom",Text="Tom"},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "John",Text="John"},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "Alex",Text="Alex"},
            };
            Age = new()
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "11",Text="11"},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "12",Text="12"},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "13",Text="13"},
            };
            Score = new()
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "90.5",Text="90.5"},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "91.5",Text="91.5"},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "92.5",Text="92.5"},
            };
        }
        public List<SelectListItem> Name { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> Age { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> Score { get; set; }

    }
```

Index.cshtml   (use reflection to get property name and options)

```
@using System.Reflection;
@model WebApplication61.MyModel
@{
    var optionsRepository = new OptionsRepository();
    var modelInstance = new MyModel();
}
<form asp-action="Index">

    @foreach (var property in modelInstance.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var options = (List<SelectListItem>)optionsRepository.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(optionsRepository);

        <label>@property.Name</label>
        <select name=@property.Name asp-items="options"></select>     
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

[image]
After sumbit, the test result in controller
[image]